# Quickbooks API oauth_verifier error

Tags: python, oauth, quickbooks

I send my request_token_secret, request_token and oauth_verifier I get sent back to my callback url to https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token and get

`Provider returned: oauth_problem=permission_unknown`

I'm using this library (https://github.com/simonv3/quickbooks-python) and the get_access_token() function of the QuickBooks class.

Comment: Any headway on this? I just started hitting it today using the rauth library and making the requests explicitly.

Comment: I've been talking to the library maintainer and he posted a method he was using with his library to get it to work, so I will test that. If you're making the requests explicitly and you post the code and it works I'd consider that the answer and give you the credit.